# Throw error when unknown property found in input API request?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

Currently I'm passing Rest Request with JSON string as filter to Web API as follows,

```
http://localhost:13825/api/values/get?filter={"Name":"abcdef","Address":"Something"}
```

I have a class like follows,

```
Public class Customer
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

When I use the following code to parse JSON string to a class object it works fine,

```
public string Get(Customer filter)
{

}
```

The problem is, When I pass filter like follows,

```
filter={"Name":"abcdef","Adess":"Something"}
```

my code assigns **null** value to **Address** property of Customer class but i wanted to throw an error when a property from JSON string is not found in any of the class property.

We can use **MissingMemberHandling.Error** but it will throw error when additional properties with all the properties what we defined in class . Here the problem case is different , I wont pass Address and Name properties every time. I may or may not pass both.

So I cant give required property.

I need to throw an error when unknown property is found in input JSON string.

Comment: How about Address=null; throw;?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you detect if an object you deserialized was missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030712/can-you-detect-if-an-object-you-deserialized-was-missing-a-field-with-the-jsonco)

Comment: @Alex maybe the address is optional, in which case it *can* be null. What the OP wants to prevent is typos.

Comment: @dcastro is right and his answer worked :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set [`JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MissingMemberHandling.htm) to `MissingMemberHandling.Error`.

> Gets or sets how missing members (e.g. JSON contains a property that isn't a member on the object) are handled during deserialization.

If you want to do this globally, for all controllers, simply add this to global.asax

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
```

If you want to do this for a specific action/controller, then you have to implement `IControllerConfiguration`:

```
public class RejectUnrecognizedPropertiesAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration 
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Remove(controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

        var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
        {
            SerializerSettings = 
            {
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
            }
        };

        controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(formatter);
    }
}
```

And simply apply the `[RejectUnrecognizedProperties]` attribute to your action/controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use the "Required" annotation on the required property in your model. Like this:

```
Public class Customer
{
  [Required]
  public string Name{get;set;}
  [Required]
  public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can do a check in the action:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something with the Customer.

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With JSON.net, you could define properties like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize it this way:

```
var CustomerInstance = (Customer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONString, typeof(Customer));
```

This would throw an exception if required data is not present.