# Newtonsoft.Json: is it possible to throw error if property not present in output class?

Tags: c#, json

```
public class Output
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

string json = "{\"Property\":\"foo\", \"P2\":\"foo\"}";

var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Output), /*settings?*/); //should throw error "P2" not found in class "Output"
```

I need to throw error if JSON not exactly maps into class (i.e. not strong typed). In this case "P2" is not present in Output class, and is not valid.

**UPDATE:**

People mention about duplicate but this is not duplicate. Field is not required it is simply **DOES NOT EXIST** in **output class**. Nothing to be marked with required attribute, please, read more carefully next time.

Comment: You want [`JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm).  See [Can you detect if an object you deserialized was missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21032130/3744182).

Comment: You, sir, saved my day =)