# C# expando creating from JSON with validity check against Linked Classes model

Tags: c#, properties, expandoobject

I have the below rather simple build of classes, they represent a model, kindly note the linked classes (initialization included in appropriate instance constructors of each one):

```
    public class DataClass
    {
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public PartClass part { get; set; }
    public MemberClass member { get; set; }
    public DataClass()
    {
        part = new PartClass();
        member = new MemberClass();
    }
}
public class PartClass
{
    public int seriesNum { get; set; }
    public string seriesCode { get; set; }
}
public class MemberClass
{
    public int versionNum { get; set; }
    public SideClass side { get; set; }
    public MemberClass()
    { side = new SideClass(); }
}
public class SideClass : IMPropertyAsStringSettable
{
    public string firstDetail { get; set; }
    public string secondDetail { get; set; }
    public bool include { get; set; }
    public SideClass() 
    { }
}
```

My problem is rather straightforward, however, the complication is on the implementation: I am creating a class dynamically, expando, and I read a JSON which, sometimes, is equivalent one-on-one with the DataClass hierarchy, like:

```
    {
    "num": "3",
    "code": "some sort of string",
    "part": {
        "seriesNum": "3",
        "seriesCode": "sample"
    },
    "member": {
        "versionNum": "1.5",
        "side": {
            "firstDetail": "aFirst",
            "secondDetail": "aSecond",
            "include": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

and sometimes, only a few values are equivalent (being a sub-set of DataClass is not an error, if there is an unknown tag in JSON, this is an error - like for example, find "age": "18" in JSON, because DataClass does not contain anywhere an 'age' property etc.), like for example:

```
    {
    "num": "9",
    "part": {
        "seriesNum": "3",
    },
    "member": {
        "versionNum": "1.5",
        "side": {
            "include": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

As said, I don't care if a property - or a whole tree of properties - is missing from the JSON compared to the DataClass.

My problem is, **how to read the JSON and assign properties and values in expando, while checking that both the hierarchy as well as the property name are correct**.

Could you help me please with this?

Comment: Why not simply deserialize to `DataClass` itself, then convert to expando afterwards?

Comment: @dbc thank you for looking up to that; I tried but seems complicated, so, while deserialization using Newtonsoft works, I need to do it the other way around because I will use expando for HttpRequest and if I push the whole DataClass object, I end up having a 'body' instead of just 'headers' etc, quite complicated...
Thanks anyhow.

Comment: It's quite easy actually and can be done in a few lines, see `JsonExtensions.DeserializeSanitizedExpando(string json, Type schemaType)` in https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCOvUO.

Comment: @dbc Ok, super amazing this one (I am using Newtonsoft, happy you provided). I need to understand all, specially the `var expando = JsonExtensions.DeserializeSanitizedExpando(json, typeof(DataClass));` - so, the deserialization returns an expando where i could see for example `Console.WriteLine("expando.member.side.include: " + expando.member.side.include);` and get `true` ? Thank you for walking an extra mile for me, I appreciate !!

Comment: @dbc thank you very much! Also, a question, if I get it correctly: I am master of the DataClass (in the sense, I own it, means it follows a carved-on-stone model) but I sincerely don't know what the json will contain (a correct json string would be like the two you have in your code, either a full representation of the DataClass, or a subset of DataClass, exactly as you created) so if the json deviates even slightly (i.e. has an unknown tag or wrong hierarchy etc) I have to discard and simply throw an error.

Comment: Are you looking for `JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error`?  See: [Detect if deserialized object is missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21032130).