# Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, how to warn about missing members, but continue deserializing?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconvert

I am using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize some objects. There is a possibility that the properties in the json file may not be present in the corresponding definition. When this happens, I want to essentially ignore the field and continue deserializing, but print a warning in the console that the field was missing.

The documentation for `DeserializeObject` shows that an additional `JsonSerializerSettings` argument can be given, and that contains a [MissingMemberHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm) setting. However, the two options available for that setting are `Ignore` and `Error`. The former silently ignores missing fields and continues, and the latter stops the deserialization and throws an error. I seem to need something in between these two.

I have seen the similar question here [Detect if deserialized object is missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030712/detect-if-deserialized-object-is-missing-a-field-with-the-jsonconvert-class-in-j). However, in this question, the original post wants the deserializer to throw an error and stop deserializing. I would like it to continue, but just inform the user of the field mismatch. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;

namespace NewtonsoftJsonSample
{
  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var json = "{'name': 'john', 'age': 45, 'city': 'Bristol'}".Replace("'", "\"");

      // remember to set an error handler and to raise an error each time a member is missing
      // during deserialization
      var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
      {
        Error = OnError,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
      };

      var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Character>(json, settings);

      Console.WriteLine("Deserialized object: {0}", deserialized);
      Console.ReadLine();

      static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to find member '{0}' on object of type {1}", args.ErrorContext.Member, args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject.GetType().Name);
        
        // set the current error as handled
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public class Character
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return $"Name: {this.Name}";
    }
  }
}
```

Basically you need to use both [`MissingMemberHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm) and [`Error`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) properties of [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) class.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed! I'm glad there is a solution that doesn't require a different package.